# trying to clone pypy's mercurial repo on windows

Tags: python, svn, mercurial, pypy

Trying to clone the pypy repo on my windows machine for some reason.  I have mercurial installed, but I do not have svn installed.  I know they just did the migration, but I didn't think I would need svn installed too? Here is the output from my terminal.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\blahblah\programming>hg clone https://bitbucket.org/pypy
/pypy
destination directory: pypy
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 40119 changesets with 127911 changes to 29936 files (+56 heads)
updating to branch default
abort: '"svn"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Do I need svn?  If so, why?  If not, what happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This repository uses several SVN [subrepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository).

```
$ cat .hgsub
greenlet = [svn]http://codespeak.net/svn/greenlet/trunk/c
testrunner = [svn]http://codespeak.net/svn/pypy/build/testrunner
lib_pypy/pyrepl = [svn]http://codespeak.net/svn/pyrepl/trunk/pyrepl/pyrepl
lib_pypy/sqlite3 = [svn]http://codespeak.net/svn/pypy/pysqlite2
```

This means that you *will* need subversion to update.  I believe you'll find that you've pulled the repository successfully, it just can't update it without having the `svn` binary.

Comment: Thanks.  You were right about the repo being there.  I just couldn't do an update.  I installed the [SilkSVN client](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download) and now I can run hg update.